# wpf datagrid text validation tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro, fluentvalidation

Think my binding is off somewhere, I would like to show the validation error as a tool tip in the datagrid. I would appreciate someone making a suggestion on how to accomplish this or point out my mistake

My Simple Test Model:

```
    public class TimeSheets
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double MondayTime { get; set; }
}
```

The View:

```
    public class TimeSheets
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double MondayTime { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class DataGridViewModel : Screen, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private BindableCollection<TimeSheets> _times = new BindableCollection<TimeSheets>();
    private readonly DataGridViewModelValidator _dgVal;
    public BindableCollection<TimeSheets> Times
    {
        get { return _times; }
        set { _times = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Times);
        }
    }
    public DataGridViewModel()
    {
        Times.Add(new TimeSheets { Id = 1, MondayTime = 3.5 });
        _dgVal = new DataGridViewModelValidator();
    
    }
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {

            var firstOrDefault =_dgVal.Validate(this).Errors.FirstOrDefault(lol => lol.PropertyName == columnName);
            if (firstOrDefault != null)
                return _dgVal != null ? firstOrDefault.ErrorMessage : "";
            return "";
        }
    }
    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dgVal != null)
            {
                FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult results = _dgVal.Validate(this);
                if (results != null && results.Errors.Any())
                {
                    string errors = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
                    return errors;
                }
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Class Model Validation:

```
 public class TimeSheetValidator:AbstractValidator<TimeSheets>
{
    public TimeSheetValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
                .Empty()
                .WithMessage("Empty ID");
        RuleFor(x => x.MondayTime)
            .Empty()
            .WithMessage("Time Empty");
        RuleFor(x => x.MondayTime)
            .Equal(3.5)
            .WithMessage("Valildation");
    }
}
```

ListValidation from the Viewmodel:

```
enter cod public class DataGridViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<DataGridViewModel>
{
    public DataGridViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(x => x.Times).SetValidator(new TimeSheetValidator());
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your XAML looks something like,

```
<DataGrid ToolTip="{Binding Error}">
    ......
</DataGrid>
```

you will the Errors property value when initializing the WPF components. If you want to update this you have to call an `OnpropertyChanged` delegate for `Error` to triggern a binding refresh. This should do it as you already provide the data in `Error.Get`.